# what is Thread Leak and Thread Dump in Java

Tags: java

**Can you please Explain me what is Thread Leak and Thread Dump in Java? 
 I am just confuse about thread Dump.**

Let me know the other way of creating thread except Thread class and runnable interface?

Comment: A thread leak is a resource leak where the resource being leaked is a thread. A thread dump is a way to dump all the information of threads for analysis (such as finding thread leaks).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [docs](http://www.javasanity.org/understandingthreaddumps):

> The thread dump is a snapshot of exactly what's executing at a moment
>   in time

And thread leak is when we dont close the thread properly then the number of unused threads grows with time.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I am clear about thread leak, but still I am not clear about thread dump. Can you please give me some example?

Comment: @user3024314:- Go through this doc: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/03/jvm-how-to-analyze-thread-dump.html You will get the details about it

Comment: Thanks @Rahul Tripathi

Comment: We *do not need to close threads*, instead we may need to call `join()` in main-thread to wait for running threads. It is totally fine main exits without waiting for running thread....a thread can not exists without main thread (without a process). So the definition "thread leak is when we dont close the thread properly" is incorrect (even if picked from good book). If thread allocated some resource (say memory) and do not release that memory then it is not thread leak -- that would be memory leak. Thread leak happen when you create unbounded threads -- that is number of thread your needed.